# throw exception without breaking loop in java

Tags: java, exception

I need to handle custom exception in java inside loop so i am throwing new custom exception but it breaks the loop. How we can manage to throw loop without breaking loop. Here is my code

```
    for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
        File currFile = arrayOfFile1[i];
        if (currFile.isFile()) {
            if (currFile.exists()) {
                try {
                    String fileName = currFile.getName();
                    if (fileName.startsWith("~$")) {
                        continue;
                    } else {
                        if ((fileName.endsWith(".xlsx")) || (fileName.endsWith(".xls"))) {
                            if (fileName.endsWith("_arch.xlsx") || fileName.endsWith("_arch.xls")) {
                                continue;
                            }
                            try {
                                IDSOutputGenerator.generateOutput(currFile.getAbsolutePath(), "", outputType,
                                        false);
                            } catch (CheckErrorHandle e) {
                                throw new CheckErrorHandle();
                            }
                        }
                        else if (fileName.endsWith(".xml")) {
                            try {
                                IDSOutputGenerator.generateOutput(currFile.getAbsolutePath(), "", outputType,
                                        false);
                            } catch (CheckErrorHandle e) {
                                throw new CheckErrorHandle();
                            }

                        } else {
                            throw new CheckErrorHandle(currFile.getAbsolutePath(), "File type not supported");
                        }
                    }
                } catch (CheckErrorHandle e) {
                    throw new CheckErrorHandle();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    throw new CheckErrorHandle("", e.getMessage());
                }
            } else {
                throw new CheckErrorHandle(currFile.getAbsolutePath(), "File does not exist");
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: if you throw the exception, you go out of the loop. what else should it do? what you can do, is create a list of exceptions, don't throw any, but add them to the list, and after the loop, throw an exception containing that list (if it's not empty-) but why would you want to do that?

Answer (score 7):

Something like:

```
Exception ex = null;
for (;;) {
    ex = new Exception();
}
if (ex != null) throw ex;
```

Or, as comment suggesting:

```
List<Exception> errors = new ArrayList<>();
for (;;) {
    errors.add(new Exception());
}
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    //Do something with errors
}
```

General idea is that only thing that you can do - store exception somewhere before throwing it. If you throwing exception - then only way to avoid breaking loop is to catch it immediately.

Answer (score 1):

One possibility - move the entire body of the loop into another method which handles the exceptions without re-throwing:

e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    File currFile = arrayOfFile1[i]; 
    handlefile(currFile);
}
```

and the method:

```
private void handleFile(File file) {
  //body of loop in here
  //log exceptions, don't re-throw
}
```

Another possibility is to havethe above method return a boolean success flag:

Loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < j; i++) {
    File currFile = arrayOfFile1[i]; 
    if (handlefile(currFile)) {
       //do something on success
    } else {
       //do something on failure
    }
}
```

Method:

```
private boolean handleFile(File file) {
  try {
    //do stuff
    return true;
  } catch (Exception e) { //or more specific exceptions/multi-catch
     //log exception
     return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Worked like a charm !!